# Installation of ncdf and clim.pact packages in R for windows

Tags: r

Hi I need to instal the `clim.pact` package in R but it is not available in CRAN anymore. From [this link](https://crantastic.org/packages/clim-pact) I learnt that I have to download and install the `ncdf` package first but this is not available in CRAN either and I should download it from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ncdf/). Does anyone knows how to install those?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one really easy way is to use `devtools` with the github cran repository:

```r
devtools::install_github("cran/ncdf")
devtools::install_github("cran/clim.pact")
```

You could also download the tar.gz file and then install the packages locally using the `remotes` package:

```r
remotes::install_local("path/to/archive.tar.gz")
```

Unfortunately, neither strategy worked for installing on R 3.5.2. Try this with the last known version of R that `netcdf` was released for.

Comment: tnx if someone knows with which versions it runs it will be great in order to avoid experimenting with many of them

Comment: @firmo23 looking at this a little more it may be challenging to get this working unless you can find existing *binaries* of the `ncdf` package. Something to consider is that there are other netCDF packages (e.g. `ncdf4`) that are currently supported. It may be easier to download the source code of `clim.pact` from GitHub and modify the code that calls `ncdf` functions to instead use comparable functions from `ncdf4`. Presumably, the calls to `ncdf` are simply for reading in data and are limited to the source files `cdfextract.R`and `retrieve.nc.R`.

Comment: Hmm how should I do that? Could you possibly help me with this?

Comment: @firmo23 you would need to clone the cran repository of `clim.pact` and modify the code yourself to replace references to `ncdf` functions with the equivalent `ncdf4` functions, and test that it works as expected. This would not be a trivial task, but it might not be particularly challenging either if the `ncd4` outputs don't have significantly different format from `ncdf`. `clim.pact` does not rely on any DLLs or external software, so it's just a matter of modifying the R code that deals with reading netCDF files.